# Twitter bootstrap typeahead with input masked not working until full string completed

Tags: jquery, input, mask, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to get bootstrap typeahead working with [Josh Bush](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) input jquery mask plugin. I've tried other plugin and it doesn't work either.

My autocomplete works well when I disable the masking on the input.

Here's my code:

```
$('.phonenumber').mask('(999) 999-9999');   

$('#new-message-phonenumber').typeahead({

        minLength: 2,
        property : 'name',
        source: function( typeahead, query ) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<? echo site_url('autocomplete/getClientInfoFromPhoneNumber'); ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    term: query
                },
                success: function(data) {

                    var return_list = [], i = data.length;

                    while (i--) {
                        return_list[i] = {value: data[i].value, name: data[i].screen_name, friendly_name: data[i].name, friendly_phone: data[i].friendly_phone };
                    }

                    typeahead.process(return_list);

                }

            });

        },
        onselect: function (obj) {
            $('#new-message-phonenumber').val(obj.friendly_phone);
            $('#new-message-name').val(obj.friendly_name);
        }
    });
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="span5">
            <label for="new-message-phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input class="input-block-level phonenumber required" id="new-message-phonenumber" name="new-message-phonenumber" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the browser debugger? I've already had some issues time ago due to the new jQuery version on it, because the plugin is out-of-date and won't support some current deprecated jQuery functions.